# sticky header for bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, sticky

I'm trying to make the header of my bootstrap modal stay fixed at the top when a user scrolls down. (Same idea as a pinterest modal when scrolling down)

I've included a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thetoolsmith/6878oL1n/) here.

My latest attempt with javascript is this:

```
var $stick = $('#stickyHeader');

$('#myModal').scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(scrollTop >= $stick.offset().top){
        $stick.css({'position':'fixed'});
    }
    else{
        $stick.css({'position':'relative'});
    }
});
```

I've also tried the affix class in bootstrap without any luck.

Is this possible with my current logic or is there something I'm missing?

Thanks,
-Paul

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use CSS to achieve what you require.

Here is the code that you will need to add to your CSS:

```
#IdOfYourHeader {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0; //This can be changed to the required amount
}
```

This will ensure that your header stays at the top of the browser window, and stays there even when the user scrolls down.